# Powershell checkbox, put checked items on top

Tags: powershell

Searched all over the web for a seemingly simple issue:

I have a working script involving a Checkedlistbox:

```
New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
```

I am trying to get it to behave so that all the checked items are put on top like this:

```
[x]
[x]
[x]
[ ]
[ ]
```

Now it looks like this:

```
[ ]
[ ]
[X]
[ ]
[X]
```

Getting the checklist items to sort alphabetically is easy, but i want them to sort on "selected state"

Is this even possible?

**UPDATE** -> the code:

```
$clbGroups = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$UserGroups = $clbGroups.CheckedItems
$formMain.Controls.Add($clbGroups)

$clbGroups.Location = '305, 258'
$clbGroups.Name = "clbGroups"
$clbGroups.Size = '400, 150'
$clbGroups.CheckedItems
$clbGroups.TabIndex = 37
$clbGroups.Sorted = "True"

Write-Verbose "Adding groups to checked list box"
$XML.Options.SecurityGroups.SecurityGroup | %{[Void]$clbGroups.Items.Add($_)} 

$cboGroup_SelectedIndexChanged={

Write-Verbose "Updating groups fields with list information"
$Group = @($XML.Options.Groups.Group | ? {$_.Name -match $cboGroup.Text})
$arrayGroups = @($Group | % { $_.List } | ? { $_.Type -match "SecurityGroup" } | % { $_.'#text' } )
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $clbGroups.Items.Count; $i++) { if($arrayGroups -Contains $clbGroups.Items[$i]){ $clbGroups.SetItemChecked( $i, $true ) } else { $clbGroups.SetItemChecked( $i, $false ) } }

}
```

Comment: First print all that are checked, then print all that are unchecked. This takes two loops https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.checkeditems?

Comment: Thanks, so i need to seperate them first! I was hoping for a more simple Powershell line of code, but i will look in to this GetItemCheckState loop and try to implement it in my Powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is a script that will work with `CheckedListBox` with only `CheckedItems` property. As there is no builtin sort method, the trick here is to create a custom function that will do it. That is done by **`function SortItems`** below. The function will prepare new items (checked and unchecked), clear existing, and add new ones in proper order. Additionally, it must programmatically preserve the checked state of items.

```
# Simplified form setup

$formMain = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

$clbGroups = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
$UserGroups = $clbGroups.CheckedItems
$formMain.Controls.Add($clbGroups)

1..10 | % {[void]$clbGroups.Items.Add("Group '$_'")}


# Function doing actual sort

function SortItems {
    $CheckedItems = $clbGroups.CheckedItems | % {$_}
    $UncheckedItems = $clbGroups.Items | where {$_ -notin $CheckedItems}
    $clbGroups.Items.Clear()
    $CheckedItems | % {$clbGroups.Items.Add($_)} | % {$clbGroups.SetItemChecked($_,$true)}
    $UncheckedItems | % {$clbGroups.Items.Add($_)}
}

# Add button that will trigger the sort

$sortBtn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$sortBtn.Add_Click({SortItems})
$sortBtn.Location = '15, 158'
$sortBtn.Text = 'Sort it!'
$formMain.Controls.Add($sortBtn)

# Show main form as dialog window

$formMain.ShowDialog()
```

And two comments about code

- `$CheckedItems = $clbGroups.CheckedItems | % {$_}` Second pipeline
  element is required to create a copy of items, not just reference. If
  we use just reference, variable will point to empty array after
  clearing items.
- `$CheckedItems | % {$clbGroups.Items.Add($_)} | %
  {$clbGroups.SetItemChecked($_,$true)}` Second pipeline element is
  adding items. It is returning index of newly created item. We use
  that index in third pipeline element to set its checked state to `true`

[image: Screenshot of the code above in the action]

Comment: Igor, thanks! I'm currently trying to use the code above. However it does not work yet, but also not returning errors. I removed this line: 1..10 | % {[void]$clbGroups.Items.Add("Group '$_'")}

Comment: Igor, never mind, i forgot to remove the clbgroups.sorted="true" it was obviously overruling the sorting function :-) Thank you, it works now.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Based on additional user input, this is not a suitable solution. I will post a better one.

I am not quite sure about your setup, but you might use something like this.

First, I simulate creating new CheckedListBox with 5 CheckBoxes

```
$CL = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox
1..5 | % {$CB = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox; $CB.Text = "CheckBox $_"; $CL.Items.Add($CB)}
$CL.Items | Select Text, Checked
```

Then, lets make third and fifth item checked

```
$CL.Items[2].Checked = $true
$CL.Items[4].Checked = $true
$CL.Items | Select Text, Checked
```

And then, lets sort it and print it to screen

```
$CL.Items | Sort Checked | Select Text, Checked
```

Comment: Igor, that look great, but i have no definition of what is checked or not, so i can not simply number the items, i just want the checked items, wathever they are put on top of the list. It is a long list, and i don't want to scroll through the items untill i come across a checked one, hence the search for a "put all checked items on top" property like solution.

Comment: What's going to be your event to trigger the sorting? Checking an item? A button? Very simply, I'd iterate over the list, adding the checked items first then unchecked to a new object, then clear the list and write the object back using $List.AddRange($newobj) etc

Comment: i populate the checklistbox with items from a XML. after the user selects a item from a pulldown list the boxes get ticked based on the reference from this item in the XML. I appreciate all the suggestions but i cannot seem to get it done. I updated the code in my question (the code works except for the sorting issue)